# Finding the minimum number in a Binary Tree recursively

Tags: c++, c, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

This is how my code looks

```
int main() {
//root is the rootnode of the tree
    if(root!==NULL) {
        int mini = min(root, root->data);
        printf("minimum number is %d", mini);
    }
    return 0;
}

int min(node *root, int mini) {

    if(root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    min(root->left, mini);
    min(root->right, mini);
    if(mini > root->data) {
        mini = root->data;
    }
    return mini;
}
```

It doesn't give me the minimum number in the tree. Rather, it prints the root node as the minimum.

Comment: `min(root->left, mini);` - what do you think this line does exactly?

Comment: No, that's not what that line does... Think about it, what does the `min` function do? (Or at least, what's it supposed to do?)

Comment: Hint: Why does your recursive function return an integer? To be discarded?

Comment: Oh yeah! I was discarding it. The same code worked with the following two lines.
mini = min(root->left, mini);
mini = min(root->right, mini);
Thanks (y)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the results of the recursive calls instead of throwing them away.
They are supposed to be the minimum values of the subtrees.

The minimum value in a tree is the minimum of

- The root value
- The value in the left subtree, if there is one
- The value in the right subtree, if there is one

Like this:

```
int min(node *root)
{
    int least = root->data;
    if (root->left != NULL)
    {
        least = std::min(least, min(root->left));
    }
    if (root->right != NULL)
    {
        least = std::min(least, min(root->right));
    }
    return least;
}
```

Comment: I doubt your code will work. It seems it just overwrite `least` without comparing with the current value of least.

Comment: @nielsen You should look up `std::min`.

Comment: @ molbdnilo - I was fooled by both functions having name min. My mistake - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int min(node *root, int mini) {

    if(root == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int a;
    a=min(root->left, mini);
    if(a<mini)
        mini=a;
    a=min(root->right, mini);
    if(a<mini)
        mini=a;
    if(root->data<mini)
        mini = root->data;
    return mini;
}
```

Comment: Seems strange to return -1 in case of NULL.

Comment: returns -1 for the case when the tree is empty.

Comment: since your code does not check for `root->left` and `root->right` being NULL before calling `min(root->...)` your code will always end up calling with a NULL pointer at the leafs. If a tree consists of pure positive data, your code will always give the result -1. I think you need to return `mini` in case of a NULL pointer input.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Not discarding the return value.

```
int main() {
//root is the rootnode of the tree
    if(root!==NULL) {
        int mini = min(root, root->data);
        printf("minimum number is %d", mini);
    }
    return 0;
}

int min(node *root, int mini) {

    if(root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    mini = min(root->left, mini);
    mini = min(root->right, mini);
    if(mini > root->data) {
        mini = root->data;
    }
    return mini;
}
```

Comment: The code can not compile. `if(root == NULL) { return; }` is not returning an `int`. I guess you want to `return mini;` ?